# Authentication script not executed before run active scan or crawling

Tags: owasp, zap

Good afternoon dear community,

I have an issue with owasp zap scanner.
Summary: authentication script not executed before run active scan or crawling.

Here more details:
The context authentication use script-based authentication method:
session.png

In order to authenticate script contain 4 API calls, all of them depends on each other.
auth_script.png

So, basically zap need to execute this script (all four API calls), get a cookies and use it for the further active scan.
Only one way to do so - it's to runt the script which contain 4 API calls for authentication OR run selenium script which will do the same but on UI side. 
For now I trying with script approach (which is looks easier).

But, when I start my active scan owasp zap don't run the script, but just start running the attack against the urls from 'Sites'.
active_scan.png

Can someone bring the clarity why that happens and how to setup the context/application/etc to run auth script before run the scan itself?

Until that the server return 403 for all requests because all of them not authenticated.

I hope that someone can help me, I waste already a lot of time to figure out, but still can't find the solution..

The copy of this question also here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zaproxy-users/Fs9EoasHycI

Answer (score 1):

As per my answer on the user group, the problem is that you are not giving ZAP a logged out / logged in indicator, so ZAP doesnt know when it should run the authentications script you've provided. If you can specify one of those then the script should run.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I have checked twice what I can do after read your response.
Unfortunately it's impossible to use this approach in my case, because to login the client need to send four different queries instead of just one.

I also have added '403' response as a 'Logged out indicator' and 200 response as a 'Logged in indicator'.

I see that when I start the scanner zap application does not execute the script before run the scan.
It's clearly visible in the history of the scan (list of the URLs exclude API endpoints for authentication).
Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Have replied on the ZAP User Group :)